# camunda exception: cannot set both candidateGroupIn and candidateUser

Tags: camunda

i'm migrating from activiti to camunda. already i used  query  to get all tasks that user involved to by condidateUser  or CandidateGroup properties. how i do it in camunda?

```
taskService.createTaskQuery().or().taskCandidateUser(userId).
           taskCandidateGroupIn(userRoles).endOr().active()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because before version **7.8**, camunda does not support `or()` and `Endor()` methods. if you want to use those methods change version to **7.8**.